# Jquery AutoComplete vs Gmail AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

What makes gmail autocomplete much faster than jquery autocomplete?

Everytime I type something in jquery, I need to pause for several millisecond (noticeable) stop before the choice come out, compare to Gmail where I don't need to stop typing.

Comment: Google has better servers?

Comment: You could try changing the delay option of autocomplete - try 10ms, 50ms, etc.  `$('#selector').autocomplete("option", "delay", 10);`

Comment: Google might be caching your address book locally so auto-complete doesn't have to go the server each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from jqueryrocks work for me

```
 $('#selector').autocomplete("option", "delay", 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The delay is higher on jQuery autocomplete by default to prevent queries being sent prematurely to the server (if it's a round-trip query)

Local data should be instant (untested, but no reason for it not to)

However it's normal practise to either restrict to a minimum number of characters or time delay before querying the database (imagine if you had a big data set and were querying it with j, then jo, then joh, then john) to avoid wasteful query executions